# SQLite Log-In Check username & password

Tags: java, sqlite, authentication

I am creating an Application (Using Java & SQLite)(JFrame, using Netbeans) I have users who I want to log in. (I have all the correct packages JDBC, SQLite etc)

The issue I am having seems to be getting the username/password to check against my users.db file.. I am using Java and SQLite. I'm using JDBC also.

Some of my code as an example (This sends my users information to make the account, Works fine), my database is users.db and I want to compare username/password against USERNAME & PASSWORD

```
Connection dbconn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "insert into USERS(ID, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, JAVALESSON, CLESSON, PYTHONLESSON) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:users.db");
    Statement statement = dbconn.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = dbconn.prepareStatement(query);
```

I have a UsernameLoginBox & PasswordLoginBox, How would I check USERNAME & PASSWORD (From SQLite Database) against the string in the textbox's for log in?

TRIED CODE:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    PreparedStatement pst =null;
    String sql1 = "Select * from USERS where USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?";
    try{
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    pst.setString(1, UsernameLogIn.toString());
    pst.setString(2, PasswordLogInField.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username & Password are correct");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username & Password are incorrect");
            System.out.println("Logged in");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println("Not Logged in");
    }
```

And this:

```
    Connection cbconn = null;
    Statement stmt2 = null;

    String upcheck  = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM USERS";
        ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery(upcheck);

        while (results.next()) {
        String staffname = results.getString("snameeee");
        String password =  results.getString("SPwd");

           if ((f.equals(staffname)) && (s.equals(password))) {

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");  
        }else {

         //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");
        }
        results.close();
    } catch (SQLException sql) {

        out.println(sql);
```

Comment: What things have you tried so far achieve the functionality? We cannot code the whole thing for you. Please try something on your own and if you get any errors, let us know. We would be glad to help you out.

Comment: I have attempted to select * USERNAME and PASSWORD from USERS and compare against string

Comment: Please edit your question with the code that you have tried.

Comment: Did you check in your database after the insert query? Are the values getting stored there?

Comment: Positive, My insertion code is fine, I just need to figure out how to compare database username against one in combo box, same with password

Comment: What is the error that you are getting with the approach you have tried?

Comment: No errors actually pop up, it just goes straight to  System.out.println("Not Logged in");

Comment: You are using `getText` for `username` and `toString` for `password`. Before querying, make sure you are getting the correct values for username and password. You can print them before adding them to the query.

Comment: I have done that in previous attempts, and just keep getting this error: Java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: For which thing you get that error?

Comment: Second section of code in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the query should be :

```
Select PASSWORD from USERS where USERNAME = 'theNameInTextBox';
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you change this to use prepared statements, otherwise this is an SQL injection vulnerability waiting to be exploited.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I assumed OP didn't know about prepared statements, as I regard WHERE as more fundamental, but they clearly do, so my comment can be disregarded.